# Search results URL without query string variables

Tags: search, redirect, urls

Have a search page `/search/` where we currently use URLs formatted like `/search/?q=query` for showing search results.

Now we would like to show the search results with a URL like this `/search/query/`

But for some reason WordPress doesn't like that. Whenever we try to go to the search results URL, we are redirected to the best match for "*query*".

Example `/search/barista-coffee/` => we are redirected to the post `/barista-coffee-experiences/` instead of staying on `/search/barista-coffee/`.

Anyone know how to fix this, so we can use search results urls like `/search/query/` instead of `/search/?q=query`?

Comment: Is the sole purpose of the `search` page and page template so that you can put the search at `/search/`? Are you aware of the `s` parameter and the `search.php` template?

Comment: Am aware of the s parameter, but this is data search based on custom tables. The data is not in WP (so it's not custom posts etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to share some of your code that already you used.

And you mention first line that you have search page ? what exactly you mean by that ?

WordPress have default search page did you mention that one ? if you are then try this code

```
function change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

But if you have custom page with search slug then you have to do this little-bit different way. However built-in search use always good idea.
Still you want to display search result after page slug like
domain.com/page/search-term then first you have to make search form and pass form url with your specific page one. like `<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/page-slug/' ); ?>">` and then use this code for finishing.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'change_search_url_rewrite' );
function change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if (is_search()) {
        $search_url = get_bloginfo('url') .'/search/'. urlencode(get_query_var('s')) . ((get_query_var('paged')) ? '/page/'. get_query_var('paged') .'/' : '/');
        if (!empty($_GET['s']) || !empty($_GET['paged']))
            wp_redirect($search_url);
    }
}
```

hope it makes sense!

Comment: Thanks. The search page is a standard page. In functions.php we have made filters like this: if(strpos(get_permalink(), "/soeg/") !== false) to identify that we are on a search page.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "have to make search form"?

Comment: Means create a custom search form by your self and pass your page url in form action. like `<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/page-slug/' ); ?>">`